# How do I embed a variable plus string in ASP:Label Text attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, attributes, label

Extremely new to ASPX, I'm attempting to update some existing code.  I have a tag

```
asp:Label ID="lblProjectGoal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"
Text=<%= SPCProjectYear %>+" Goals:"
AssociatedControlID="txbProjectGoal" />
```

and I need the year to be a variable that I can use in other `<asp:Label>` tags in the text attribute with differing string endings.  Anyone know the best syntax to use here for Text=<%= SPCProjectYear %>+" Goals:"? Visual Studio tells me I have the syntax wrong. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393348/how-to-use-asp-net-tags-in-server-control-attributes

Comment: You can see an example in [How to create a dynamic hyperlink in datalist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168117/how-to-create-a-dynamic-hyperlink-in-datalist/39168184#39168184).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Label createLabelText(Label l, string SPCProjectYear){
    l.Text = SPCProjectYear+" Goals:";
}
Label l = new Label();
l.ID = "lblProjectGoal";
l = createLabelText(l,SPCProjectYear);
Page.ControlsAdd(l);
```

(A clunky example -- would be optimized to add other things based on the source of your data)

Let me show it a little differently (this goes in code behind, where "myYear is the variable you're talking about)

```
string myYear = "2006";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblProjectGoal.Text = myYear + " Goals:";


    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shannon.  I'm not quite getting this, but will keep working with it.  I appreciate your responding!

Comment: I changed my example around to make it a little easier to understand. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Label Text binding like this , I am assuming you missed **EVAL** and see if this works out

```
Text='<%# Eval(SPCProjectYear)%>+ Goals:'
```

**Update**

Add this method in CodeBehind

```
public string ProcessMyDataItem(object myValue)
    {
        if (myValue.ToString() != "")
        {
                return myValue.ToString() + "Goals" ;
        }

    }
```

In **aspx**

```
Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("SPCProjectYear"))  %>'
```

Comment: Thank you for this Webruster.  It didn't seem to work, but I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @KirstenFrost please check my update and do let me know it worked for you or not